# Get facebook acces token without redirect

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, access-token

This is how I retrieve the user acces token

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
 //auth user
 if(empty($code)) {
     $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=' . urlencode('http://myweb.com/facebook.php') ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }
  //get user access_token
  $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=' . urlencode('http://myweb.com/facebook.php') 
    . '&client_secret=mybigsecret&code=' . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

But I was wondering if there's any way I can do it without any redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my coding, you can try...

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
$response = file_get_contents(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $client_id .
    "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_url .
    "&client_secret=" . $client_secret .
    "&code=" . $code
);
parse_str($response, $params);
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
$user_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
$user = $user_data->id; //get active fb user id
$facebook->setAccessToken($params['access_token']);
```

P.S. `$params['access_token']` for access_token value...

Comment: The thing is that in my code the redirect is to get the $code and this stars already with $code..

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no solution for common browsers, because Facebook set the header `X-Frame-Options:DENY` in the oauth page, which denies the usage of iframe in this case.